# After move SQL isn't releasing memory for queries

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, memory, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We recently made a move from one VM hosting environment to another.  The machine we moved is a clone so all settings are identical pre- and post-move.  However in our new environment our SQL server is filling up memory, not releasing it, and then throwing event ID 701: insufficient memory to execute query and then after enough failures terminating the SQL service.

I know filling up available memory is typical behavior for SQL and after we first saw this we ensured max memory was set to lower than the total system memory to allow room for OS processes (about 6GB lower, plenty of room).  However we are still getting this behavior and the same errors.  It appears that SQL is filling up memory and then not releasing it for its own queries then crashing.

Has anyone seen this issue or know any fix/troubleshooting steps?  Thank you.

Comment: What was the driver that made you decide to "clone" SQL server and how was that done?  Have you tried building a new server in the new environment and moving the DBs?

Comment: That's not really an option for us at the moment.  Basically, we are using a license that nobody seems to have and are unable to purchase a new one at the moment.  So we cloned to move the license intact.

Comment: @Tony May be worth looking at SQL activity (e.g. SP_WHOISACTIVE) or queries running and see what's going on such as huge transactions, etc. that may need fine tuned to use resources more effeciently...  In any case, here are a couple articles that may be helpful otherwise maybe consider moving to DBA.StackExchange. . .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537812/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-internal or http://serverfault.com/questions/10503/sql-server-2005-there-is-insufficient-system-memory-to-run-this-query